# What is the difference between $foo === TRUE and TRUE === $foo

Tags: php, boolean

I do understand that, in the following code...

```
$foo = TRUE;
$bar = 1;

if ($foo === TRUE)
{
    echo 'Foo';
}

if ($bar === TRUE)
{
    echo 'Bar';
}
```

... will only print Foo because of the Type comparison.

However, my question is regarding ...

```
if ($foo === TRUE)
{
    echo 'Foo1';
}
if (TRUE === $foo)
{
    echo 'Foo2';
}
```

... because as far as I know, they are the same, but I remember reading somewhere that they are not. Am I just dreaming weird stuff about PHP or is there actually a difference?

Thanks!

Comment: One reads more stupidly than the other.

Comment: Here ya go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions :-D

Comment: Thanks Rocket! So I was dreaming about Star Wars :D

Comment: Well I think it's useless in php, because `==` is rarely needed. Most (if not all) comparisons need `===` and it's unlikely that you can mistype that to `=`

Comment: Yoda conditions? Coding gets stranger by the day. Bemused am I.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the same - it's only that if you put $foo on right side you can be safe from that terrible mistake when you use only one "=" sign.  So it's rather a good practice to use "left comparisons".  Consider this:

```
//  These 4 lines intended for the same check
//  Notice the subtle differences!

    if("secret_thing" =  $password) {...}   // you get an error but that's it
    if("secret_thing" == $password) {...}   // this is perfect
    if($password == "secret_thing") {...}   // this is acceptable
    if($password =  "secret_thing") {...}   // you're deep in trouble, friend!

//
```

With literals on the left, the worst thing to happen is that you get an error message. No big deal. With literals on the right (and a small typo), burglars are right in your living room.

Actually, **that typo is very easy to make**, for example, if you work with Pascal / Delphi / Lazarus where you have ':=' for assignment and a simple '=' means comparison. And there's no alarm when you do it; PHP will think he understands you.

TLDR: it's a safeguard.

*Side note: you can also use a comparison function to improve readability.  But that one takes some extra microseconds so in high performance cases just stick to the good old "==" / "===" sign.*

Comment: Reading the "Yoda_conditions" wiki, it seems like some people might consider this a bad practice because of the lack of readability. Imho it seems like a good practice, though.

Comment: So you put the value on the left just to increase the visibility of your own mistake? Sounds fishy to me...

Comment: It's a good one in some cases.  There are other ways to still be safe and maintain (even improve) readability, you can write a simple function to compare things, for example.  Then you have something like "if(matches($password,"booo"))" which is fairly self-explaining.

Comment: thelolcat: nope. If you do it the other way around, your mistake will be far less serious - it throws an error instead of letting someone in with ANY password. Just think about it.

Comment: Well, actually it won't be "less serious"... it will trigger an error elsewhere and you will get crazy searching what is generating it, spending half an hour, asking your workmate, calling the police, going home and screaming at your wife and then probably ending up in jail or in a madhouse.

Answer (score 3):

They both are exactly the same

The same exactly they are ;)